# vb.net mustinherit casting child

Tags: vb.net, inheritance

I work with mustInherit Class

I create something looking like this

```
Sub OnLoad
    ...
        Dim o As Object = BaseX(Of Object).LoadItem
        dim gv as Gridview = o.AddGridview(myPanel)
    ...
end Sub

MustInherit Class BaseX(Of T1)
    Public Shared Function LoadItem() As Object
        ...
            'Create Item FirstX or SecondX
            'return the new Item
        ...
    End Function

    Public Function GetGridview(ByVal container As Panel) As Gridview
        'return a gridview
    End Function
End Class

Class FirstX Inherits BaseX(of A)
...
End Class

Class SecondX Inherits BaseX(of B)
...
End Class
```

I got an error on  "dim gv as Gridview = o.AddGridview(myPanel)"

> Error 18  Late bound resolution; runtime errors could occur.
>
> Error 19  Warning treated as error : Late bound resolution; runtime
>   errors could occur.

I try

```
Dim gv As GridView = DirectCast(o, BaseX(Of Object)).AddGridview(myPanel)
```

but I got a runtime error

> Can't cast the object type FirstX on type BaseX

If you got a way to go? What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cast BaseX(of Object) to FirstX since FirstX is inherited from BaseX(of A).
Even though A inherits from Object, BaseX(Of Object) is not the parent of BaseX(of A).

Consider this:

```
Class A
    public overrides Sub ToString()
         Console.Writeline("A")
    End Sub
End Class

Class FirstX Inherits BaseX(of A)
    public overrides Sub ToString()
         A.ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

You can see that BaseX(Of Object).ToString() is not the same as BaseX(of A).ToString(), it is two completely different classes which do not inherit one from another.

To solve your issue you either directly cast to FirstX, or to BaseX(of A). I would suggest, for the sake of extensebility, to create an interface IBaseX which is implemneted by BaseX(of T). Then u can always upcast to the interface.

```
Interface IBaseX
    Function GetGridview(ByVal container As Panel) As Gridview
End Interface

MustInherit Class BaseX(Of T1)
    Implements IBaseX

    Public Shared Function LoadItem() As Object
        ...
            'Create Item FirstX or SecondX
            'return the new Item
        ...
    End Function

    Public Function GetGridview(ByVal container As Panel) As Gridview
        Implements IBaseX.GetGridView
        'return a gridview

    End Function

End Class
```

Upcasting:

```
Dim gv As GridView = CType(o, IBaseX).AddGridview(myPanel)
```

Note: This is VB.NET code, it might not work in Excels VB 6.0